# How to confirm that a session token is used in google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Using Google's widget to implement a places' search and trying to figure out and confirm that Google is charging for a session and not per keystroke. Is it possible to figure that out by looking at the network tab or similar?

The screenshot below was captured after performing two small queries:

[image]

If there is a better way to confirm please feel free to share.

Comment: If you are already using the [Autocomplete Widget](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) then you don't need to worry about the session tokens as they are being implemented automatically. The only time you should watch for session tokens is when you are using [JS Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction). If you are using the JS Autocomplete Service and want to check the session tokens, it's best to file a support case for better analysis by the tech team.

Comment: Yeah, we are using the Autocomplete Widget but we are still seeing high number of transactions however there is one implementation where we make some modifications to the Widget at runtime and I was wondering if that was affecting it thus wanting to confirm on the session-token.

Comment: I see, this is better to be discussed with the tech team as they are equipped to investigate such scenarios, I suggest you create a sample in JSFiddle taht they can review to check if your implementation is using session tokens properly, or if you have it live on website, just provide them the link to your site. You can file the support case by following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#creating-a-support-case)

Comment: Thanks! I am going to go that route, I am surprised there is no way to confirm that on our own without having to reach out to them directly.